# SQL Server iterate in select query and update upon condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following result from query

```
empId   totalPoints  addPointsDate  incidentDate
-------------------------------------------------
 1           11        2015-06-04    2015-07-11
 2           12        2015-07-04    2015-08-16
 3           10        2015-08-04    2015-06-14
 4           9         2015-06-14    2015-09-11
```

I have to update the total points if the addPointsDate was 5 weeks ago and I didn't have any incidentDate during this period.

Can I do that with stored procedure or I have to use sql function

Comment: Are you looking for a solution or for a "yes" or "no"? I would use plain SQL (this is just a simple `UPDATE` statement) or a procedure -- functions expect return values which you don't need.

Comment: I have to update the result upon the conditions, that's why I thought that I have to iterate through each row, check for the conditions and then update

Comment: (1) Precisely 5 weeks ago, or more than 5 weeks ago? (2) Incident date occurred after addPointsDate (and within the 5 week period)? This is otherwise a slightly tricky `where` clause on your update statement.

Comment: more than 5 weeks ago

Answer (score 1):

I would use plain SQL (this is just a simple UPDATE statement) or a procedure -- functions expect return values which you don't need.

```
UPDATE
    pointsTable
SET
    totalPoints = totalPoints + 1
WHERE
    -- More than 5 weeks ago
    DATEDIFF(DAY, addPointsDate, GETDATE()) > 35 -- 5 weeks * 7 days
    AND
    -- No incidents, or incident was before the add points date
    (incidentDate IS NULL OR incidentDate < addPointsDate)
```

Comment: How can I check for the conditions in your solution

Comment: The conditions are in the `WHERE` -- an `UPDATE` statement affects all the rows (one by one) wherever there is a match based on the `WHERE` constraints. Do you have a test database or table? I would suggest just running the above and checking whether it does what you want, then you can tweak it as you see fit.

Comment: The datediff means that week has changed over 5 times, not that it's more than 5 weeks ago. There is a small difference. It's better to use days * 7.

Answer (score 1):

A simple update is sufficient:

```
update mytable
set totalPoints = totalPoints + 1
    , addPointsDate = getdate()
where
    addPointsDate <= dateadd(week, -5, getdate()) -- add points was before 5 weeks ago
    and incidentDate < addPointsDate -- last incident was before add points
```